# What is a ListBox' DrawItem

Tags: c#, skype

I'm sorry for the inconvenient question. I made a post about how to do like skypes message list? And a user said add a ListBox' DrawItem

I would like to know. Well ask what a ListBox' DrawItem is
And is there and easy tutorials to make One. 
Im brand new with c#  and I am unsure
what it is. I've researched it and cannot find any images or info about what it is.

Answer (score 1):

`DrawItem` is an event given to a `WinForms` `Listbox` to custom draw a particular item.  A custom listbox class could implement this by overriding the OnDrawItem method.  More information can be found in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem(v=vs.110).aspx